# Assign variables to all files in a folder for access

Tags: python, file, pickle

I have a folder that contains'.pkl' files. I want to access the data inside those multiple files to plot my results.

I am getting an error when I try to do it with a for loop. All my .pkl files contain numbering in their filename like meta_room_1_reg.pkl, meta_room_2_reg.pkl and so on. So I want to assign a single variable to each and every one.

Currently, I am doing that with an if and find() statement. But that is not ideal.

My code is here:

```
all_files = glob.glob('D:/Master Thesis/MCDM Combined code/results/*.pkl')
for i, curr_file in enumerate(all_files):
    with open(curr_file, 'rb') as f:
        mydata = pickle.load(f)
        if curr_file.find('1'):
            myfile = mydata
```

Please guide.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: myfile[i] = mydata
IndexError: list assignment index out of range

And i tried a few other things but i don't know why I cannot iterate

Comment: i did create myfile = [] before that

Comment: But you didn't add anything to variable myfile, you overwrote it with mydata. Try changing the last line with `myfile.append(mydata)`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you want to collect all data to list or something like that, right?

Use the `.append` method, instead of just an assignment.

```py
    myfiles = []
    all_files = glob.glob('D:/Master Thesis/MCDM Combined code/results/*.pkl')
    for i, curr_file in enumerate(all_files):
        with open(curr_file, 'rb') as f:
            mydata = pickle.load(f)
            if curr_file.find('1'):
                myfiles.append(mydata)
```

Comment: I think I was doing something stupid before when I tried it. I changed my code a bit and it worked. Thank :)